# How can I read a task's 'params' value during unit testing in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Taskqueue stub in google app engine. It is very nice, but there is one thing that is driving me nuts.

During my test, a method I'm testing creates a task, and I want to check if that task has been created correctly. So, one of the things I have to check is that the proper 'params' have been passed. To do that, I do the following to get the task:

```
tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.GetTasks(queue_name)
self.assertEqual(1, len(tasks))
task = tasks[0]
```

But this task does not have a 'params' key, which is a shame, because that info is very valuable to assert that everything is fine.

Instead, the task has a 'body' key, which contains a base64 encoded version of the request body, something like this (once base64decoded):

> muted=False&class_=Decoder&failures=3&last_orders=Key%28%27ProspectiveSale%27%2C+%27cl1%27%29&last_orderl=Key%28%27ProspectiveSale%27%2C+%27cl2%27%29&hit_per=5.0

I have tried to parse that to get the 'params' dict, but I'm finding it a bit tedious to parse all different items to their corresponding types, etc. Somehow, I feel that is just wrong, there has to be a simpler way to do this.

So, to consider this question as answered, I would need one of the following:

- A way to read the 'params' dict.
- A way to reconstruct the 'params' dict from the 'body' value mentioned above.
- Another solution that I cannot imagine now but that would let me read that frikin 'params' dict ;-)

Cheers!

Comment: Is [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) helpful. It creates a dict from a query string.

Comment: Yes it is, although I was already manually parsing that string, using urlparse is much better. I still was having the problem that I was stupidly comparing my original dict which contained non-string values with the parsed string (where every value is a string). But your solution worked for reconstructing 'params' as it will be seen by the request handler, so if you want, post it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module has a function for converting a parameter string to a dict: [`parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs).

For example:

```
import urlparse

params = 'muted=False&class_=Decoder&failures=3&last_orders=Key%28%27ProspectiveSale%27%2C+%27cl1%27%29&last_orderl=Key%28%27ProspectiveSale%27%2C+%27cl2%27%29&hit_per=5.0'
print urlparse.parse_qs(params)
```

prints the following:

```
{'muted': ['False'], 'class_': ['Decoder'], 'hit_per': ['5.0'], 'last_orders': ["Key(
'ProspectiveSale', 'cl1')"], 'last_orderl': ["Key('ProspectiveSale', 'cl2')"], 'failu
res': ['3']}
```